# Bad estimations in execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execution-plan, cardinality-estimates

I have a weird problem in regards of cardinal estimation in SQL Server 2012 (11.0.2218).

All statistics are updated using sp_updatestats but some operators display just 1 estimated row, even if actual rows after execution are much higher.
Query performs poorly(around 1 min).

Can you explain to me what I need to change to improve those estimations? Or it's a bug in SQL Server engine?

Here is [actual plan](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhdjYi359YDThQOeqx3lL41GCh7A) for query.

Comment: Which specific operator in the plan are you referring to? I did a quick scan and on a lot of them, estimates & actuals matched.

Comment: I think https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhdjYi359YDThQRTkoqKZuNlkhSx can cause problems.

Comment: Ook i think i did something wrong with join... Sorry, just had a tough day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you were playing around with join hints. Those are very last resort anyone should do when comes to query optimization. `MERGE` keyword forces a physical operation on logical `INNER JOIN` operation. I would recommend running query in [PlanExplorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) completely free tool (no contact information required) and looking at index analysis that gets information on statistics.

```
SELECT  s.StudentID
      , s.LastName
      , s.FirstName
      , s.MiddleName
      , s.PassportSeries
      , s.PassportNumber
      , s.PassportIssued
      , s.PassportDate
      , ssp.DepartmentID
      , bd.BookerId AS [DepartmentUuid]
FROM    dbo.StudentDetailsView sdv
JOIN    Students s
        ON s.StudentID = sdv.StudentID
JOIN    StudentSpecialities ssp
        ON ssp.ID = sdv.StudentSpecialityID
JOIN    Booker_Departments bd
        ON bd.UniversityId = ssp.DepartmentID
JOIN    StudentFoundations sf
        ON sf.ID = sdv.StudentFoundationID
LEFT JOIN StudentStates ss
        ON ss.ID = sdv.StudentStateID
INNER MERGE JOIN StudentSettlements sse
        ON sse.StudentID = sdv.StudentID
WHERE   ss.ID IS NULL
        AND ( ssp.EndDate IS NULL
              OR ssp.EndDate >= GETDATE()
            )
        AND ( sf.EndDate IS NULL
              OR sf.EndDate >= GETDATE()
            )
        AND ( sf.FoundationID = 7
              OR sf.FoundationID = 10
            )
```

Looking at your query and execution plan I noticed the following filter

```
[dbo].[Students].[StudentID] = [dbo].[Students].[StudentID]
```

[image]

which made no sense as it is self-join back to the table. After carefully looking at your plan I realized that you are bringing back data from a view and then joining it back to the base tables that are present in the view. It is a known issue that nested views will always produce estimated row count of 1 no matter how much you update statistics. My recommendation is to rewrite query without use of `StudentDetailsView` which just hinders performance.

Remember: Views are not for performance, they are for simplicity and easy of access of information.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I didn't know that self joins will produce bad estimations. 
The main purpose of the self joins here is to retrieve the most current record from history tables and join this record with StudentID, so I can use this view as starting point for quering information about this entity aggregate.
I just rewrote query a little bit and I still a bit confused about <a href="https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhdjYi359YDThQhrqEEwybNd9mtl">execution results</a>.
How can I achieve this task without self joins?

Comment: Sorry for bad links. I'm new to stackexchange.
Here is right link to plans. 
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhdjYi359YDThQlm42USY40dRapU

Comment: I did not say that self-joins produce bad estimation but rather that views can produce a bad estimate. Can you rewrite query without use of the view?

Comment: Look into SQL Server `OVER` clause, you can use something like a `ROW_NUMBER` to defined which records are newer and then filter to only the newest record.